# Use environment vars of container in command key of docker-compose

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have two services in my `docker-compose.yml`: docker-gen and nginx. Docker-gen is linked to nginx. In order for docker-gen to work I must pass the actual name or hash of nginx container so that docker-gen can restart nginx on change.

When I link docker-gen to nginx, a set of environment variables appears in the docker-gen container, the most interesting to me is `NGINX_NAME` – it's the name of nginx container.

So it should be straightforward to put `$NGINX_NAME` in `command` field of service and get it to work. But `$NGINX_NAME` doesn't expand when I start the services. Looking through docker-gen logs I see the lines:

```
2015/04/24 12:54:27 Sending container '$NGINX_NAME' signal '1'
2015/04/24 12:54:27 Error sending signal to container: No such container: $NGINX_NAME
```

My `docker_config.yml` is as follows:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:latest
  ports:
    - '80:80'
  volumes:
    - /tmp/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d

dockergen:
  image: jwilder/docker-gen:latest
  links:
    - nginx
  volumes_from:
    - nginx
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    - ./extra:/etc/docker-gen/templates
    - /etc/nginx/certs
  tty: true
  command: >
    -watch
    -only-exposed
    -notify-sighup "$NGINX_NAME"
    /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Is there a way to put environment variable placeholder in command so it could expand to actual value when the container is up?

Comment: Is the env variable not getting parsed and just being passed as a string? Try taking the double quotes off and post back the message.

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I remove double quotes I get the same message. Same goes for `${NGINX_NAME}`

Comment: I think that environment variables are not substituted because the entrypoint of docker-gen is `/usr/local/bin/docker-gen` and not `/bin/sh -c`. It simply doesn't know what to do with variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've added `entrypoint` setting to dockergen service and changed `command` a bit:

```
dockergen:
  image: jwilder/docker-gen:latest
  links:
    - nginx
  volumes_from:
    - nginx
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock
    - ./extra:/etc/docker-gen/templates
    - /etc/nginx/certs
  tty: true
  entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
  command: >
    "
    docker-gen
    -watch
    -only-exposed
    -notify-sighup $(echo $NGINX_NAME | tail -c +2)
    /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl
    /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    "
```

Container names injected by Docker linking start with '/', but when I send `SIGHUP` to containers with leading slash, the signal doesn't arrive:

```
$ docker kill -s SIGHUP /myproject_dockergen_1/nginx
```

If I strip it though, nginx restarts as it should. So this `$(echo $NGINX_NAME | tail -c +2)` part is here to remove first char from `$NGINX_NAME`.

Comment: Many thanks for this.  You set me on the right track.  I had completely missed the "unable to reststart nginx" message.